# Wagtail/Django internationalization Language select

Tags: python, django, internationalization, multilingual, wagtail

I am having a bit of a dilema with Wagtail internationalization.

my url.py looks like this

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^django-admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

#url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),

# For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
# Wagtail's page serving mechanism. This should be the last pattern in
# the list:
url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),

# Alternatively, if you want Wagtail pages to be served from a subpath
# of your site, rather than the site root:
#    url(r'^pages/', renders(wagtail_urls)),
url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
# These URLs will have /<language_code>/ appended to the beginning
url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),
url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),

)
```

base settings file looks like this

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

'wagtail.wagtailcore.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
'wagtail.wagtailredirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',


]
```

Then my menu template looks like this

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}" />
                    <select name="language" onclick="Bonjour">
                        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                        {% for language in languages %}
                            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                            </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
                </form>
```

However every time I select a language it goes to page not found (404). I have gone over the wagtail 1.9 docs and I can't find where I am at fault.

The wired thing it keeps saying

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8002/en/i18n/setlang/
Raised by:  wagtail.wagtailcore.views.serve`
```

and the form is a POST.Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your first `url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),` line needs to be commented out.

Comment: @gasman you sir need a medal. Thank you can't believe I didn't see that.